# NFS Client for use in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to do a proof of concept for accessing files from an NFS v4.1 server via a lambda function. Of the supported languages, I personally prefer Python... but I have been looking at the other languages as well and have yet to find a library to support this. I'd rather not build an NFS client from scratch and since this is Lambda, I have limited OS access so it's not as simple as mounting it on the OS and using os.system (or the more politically correct newer shell command functions) to run the OS equivalent.

Anyone have experience with doing this sort of thing or can link me to a completely native python nfs client for v4.1 (or really a native client for any lambda supported language: python, nodejs, go, c#, java)?